# golang get udp socket buffer size

Tags: sockets, go, udp, buffer

I'm writing a udp client and set udp socket send buffer by SetWriteBuffer.

```
   addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8089")
   conn, err :=net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)  
   err =conn.SetWriteBuffer(64*1024*1024)
```

as above, how can I test set the value is effective or get the send buffer value after  call SetWriteBuffer function.
Thank you all.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? Surely there is a `GetWriteBuffer()` method?

Comment: I have look through golang package about net package ,  but I have  not see   GetWriteBuffer() method .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the net package code, it looks like SetWriteBuffer makes a syscall to setsockopt (for posix). There is no similar function for GetWriteBuffer. The only way i can think to do this is by making another syscall to getsockopt like so.

```
addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8089")
conn, _ := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)
conn.SetWriteBuffer(10 * 1024)
fd, _ := conn.File()
value, _ := syscall.GetsockoptInt(int(fd.Fd()), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_SNDBUF)
log.Println(value)
fd.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: it works well ,  very thanks,  and  the get value is double   of set buffer value

Answer (score 1):

Check the error value returned by `SetWriteBuffer`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8089")
    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)

    err = conn.SetWriteBuffer(64 * 1024 * 1024)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,  I use it and  no error output,  and have any method to get the  value of send buffer  after setting the udp buffer.